# Count the elapsed days from the beginning of the fiscal for each quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that is a simple count of the quarters, but I wish instead to produce an accumulative counting according to the Year to Date (not the previous record). Is the only way to achieve this is through pointers?

MS SQL Server and the datatype of TPO_CQuarter is varchar.

Desired result:

```
TPO_CQuarter Days
2016-1  112
2016-2  196
2016-3  280
2016-4  364
2017-1  111
2017-2  195
2017-3  279
2017-4  363
2018-1  112
2018-2  196
2018-3  280
2018-4  298
```

Query:

```
SELECT T.TPO_CQuarter
,COUNT(DISTINCT TPO_CFecha)
FROM TH_Rotacion R
INNER JOIN TD_Tiempo T ON R.TPO_KFECHA=T.TPO_KFecha
GROUP BY T.TPO_CQuarter
ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter ASC
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What's the datatype of `TPO_CQuarter`, `VarChar`?

Comment: RDBMS -> MS SQL Server. Datatype of TPO_CQuarter -> varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a year column, you can express this as:

```
SELECT T.TPO_CQuarter,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TPO_CFecha) as days_in_quarter,
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINcT TPPO_CFecha) OVER (PARTITION BY T.TPC_CYear ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter) as days
FROM TH_Rotacion R INNER JOIN
     TD_Tiempo T
     ON R.TPO_KFECHA = T.TPO_KFecha
GROUP BY T.TPO_CQuarter, T.TPO_CYear
ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter ASC;
```

If not, you can use `LEFT()`:

```
SELECT T.TPO_CQuarter,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TPO_CFecha) as days_in_quarter,
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT TPPO_CFecha) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(T.TPO_CQuarter, 4) ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter) as days
FROM TH_Rotacion R INNER JOIN
     TD_Tiempo T
     ON R.TPO_KFECHA = T.TPO_KFecha
GROUP BY T.TPO_CQuarter
ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TPO_CQuarter, SUM(Days) OVER (ORDER BY TPO_CQuarter) CumSum FROM (
    SELECT T.TPO_CQuarter
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT TPO_CFecha) Days
    FROM TH_Rotacion R
    INNER JOIN TD_Tiempo T ON R.TPO_KFECHA=T.TPO_KFecha
    GROUP BY T.TPO_CQuarter
    ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter ASC
) a
```

Window function `SUM` with `ORDER BY` clause acts as cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *Cumulative Sum/Running Total*:

```
SELECT T.TPO_CQuarter
   -- cumulative sum
   ,SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT TPO_CFecha))
    OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(TPO_CFecha FROM 1 FOR 4) -- reset for each year
          ORDER BY TPO_CQuarter
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM TH_Rotacion R
INNER JOIN TD_Tiempo T ON R.TPO_KFECHA=T.TPO_KFecha
GROUP BY T.TPO_CQuarter
ORDER BY T.TPO_CQuarter ASC
```